# Framework design for services

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am working on this application for which we have to write framework services like reporting, logging, exception handling, security. Since these services are are to be used through the project, i am thinking of exposing the instances of these services through a service container which has reference to the objects of these individual services. 
Although i can somehow write it but i want to do it in a good design-pattern oriented way.

How to go about solving this problem? Any reference to where this problem has already been tackled with.

Thanks

Edit: I was reading some thing about service layers. Doesn't it have to do something with facade pattern??I dont know....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [Unity (IOC container)](http://unity.codeplex.com/) for [Inversion of Control](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) (aka Dependency Injection, DI). Another popular one is [Structure Map](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/index.html).

This allows you to build services using Interfaces and letting the IOC Container handle concrete implementations.

If you are talking physical seperation of services you might want to look into [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx)

Comment: well.i dont want to use another framework. I have write my own implementation (due to some reasons). Do we have a working sample somewhere showing the architecture/pattern?

Comment: Basic IOC is easy to implement. Here's an article I used in the past to implement it http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/10/20/Building-an-IoC-container-in-15-lines-of-code.aspx .

Answer (score 1):

Check MEF (.NET 4.0) to construct an application from different assemblies. What you look for is an IOC system that does dependency injection. I build a larger application from a "Server core" and "Services" that get loaded in.